# Postgresql 9.5 JSONB nested arrays LIKE statement

Tags: arrays, postgresql, nested

I have a jsonb column, called "product", that contains a similar jsonb object as the one below. I'm trying to figure out how to do a LIKE statement against the same data in a postgresql 9.5.

```
{
  "name":"Some Product",
  "variants":[
    {
      "color":"blue",
      "skus":[
        {
          "uom":"each",
          "code":"ZZWG002NCHZ-65"
        },
        {
          "uom":"case",
          "code":"ZZWG002NCHZ-65-CASE"
        },
      ]
    }
]}
```

The following query works for exact match.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product#> '{variants}' @> '[{"skus":[{"code":"ZZWG002NCHZ-65"}]}]';
```

But I need to support LIKE statements like "begins with", "ends width" and "contains". How would this be done?

Example: Lets say I want all products returned that have a sku code that begins with "ZZWG00".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should unnest `variants` and `skus` (using `jsonb_array_elements()`), so you could examine `sku->>'code'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM 
    products p,
    jsonb_array_elements(product->'variants') as variants(variant),
    jsonb_array_elements(variant->'skus') as skus(sku)
WHERE
    sku->>'code' like 'ZZW%';
```

Use `DISTINCT` as you'll have multiple rows as a result of multiple matches in one `product`.

Comment: Will this still take advantage of indexes?

Comment: Still? There is no word about indexes in the question. What indexes do you mean?

Comment: My apologies.. I'm using.. 
`CREATE INDEX on products USING GIN (product jsonb_path_ops);`

Comment: No, the index will not be used as it supports only `@>` operator. Note however, that you are going to use `like`, in which case such indexes are useless.